# os.makedirs generates exception when a file exists with the same name in Python 2.7.10

Tags: python, darwin, os.path

Creating intermediate directories and leaf directory fails like the following example conditions (in MAC OS Darwin). There is a 'test' file in '/tmp' directory:

```
if os.path.isfile('/tmp/test'):
    if os.path.isdir('/tmp/test') is False:
        os.makedirs('/tmp/test')

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-45-71969e2d9a17>", line 3, in <module>
os.makedirs('/tmp/test')
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists: '/tmp/test'
```

How can I create directories in this case?

Comment: Your example checks if the file `/tmp/test` exists, which must return `True` if the rest of your example code runs. The next check is that `/tmp/test` is not a directory, which given we know it's a file, also passes. Then `os.makedirs` tries to create a directory, where there is already a file. Python quite rightly does not let you make a directory where there is already a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon Walker states this not a bug in Python or an implementation error. Operating systems (not only Darwin but other OSs like Windows) do not allow having a file and a directory with the same name in a directory. See an [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22447) for Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a temporary directory, use `tempfile.mkdtemp()`.